invalid command name 'main:app' when I execute "uvicorn main:app --reload"
When I try to execute the command uvicorn main:app --reloadfor start my local server, the VSCode terminal throws the error invalid command name 'main:app'. The code below imports a variable from the pipeline of the generative AI model using FastAPI to estabilish a route for the generated responses. I guess the trick is in the main method that imports uvicorn library and uses it to run the app, apparently the code is right but maybe I missed something.
#main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import sys
import os

# Adds the root directory to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from src.inference.pipeline import generate_response
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(input_text: str):
    response = generate_response(input_text)
    return {"response": response}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)


I believe main:app assumes that your code has defined a function named app(), which this code does not have.

So if I rename the "predict" function to "app" maybe the code can work?

I confirmed here, what I put as a hypothesis didn't work

Does your project has a package named app or module named app.py? This may interfere with uvicorn.

@JohnGordon FastAPI object defines __call__, it is callable, so it's fine. I use the exact same starting scripts as here and never had issue.

Are you running this in the same directory as main.py?  Have you tried running in a regular terminal, not the vs code terminal?

@RibomBalt it doesn't have a package or module named app

@John Gordon I tried to run the command in Windows Command Prompt and Powershell, it throwed the same error. Thank you for the help, guys!

@JohnGordon I'm running in the same directory as main.py, actually

Decouple the main and app logic.
Place this part under server.py file in the same directory:
# server.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import sys
import os

# Adds the root directory to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from src.inference.pipeline import generate_response
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(input_text: str):
    response = generate_response(input_text)
    return {"response": response}

In the main.py keep only this part:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run("server:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)

Note that "server:app" indicates "module:app" path.

It works! Thanks to your response, I was able to understand the previously published answer about "How to run Uvicorn FastAPI server as a module from another Python file?" Thank you!
